# Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I have used the code like below code. I am getting this exception. I checked the several links according to that links I have done my code. but still get issue 
Please advice me to overcome from this issue

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the       google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at  https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.6.

My gradle like this

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
final RETROFIT = '2.3.0'
final SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '25.3.1'
final FIREBASE_VERSION = '10.0.1'
final PLAY_SERVICE = '10.2.6'

//support
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"


compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

//api inspection
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.4.2'

//api
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$RETROFIT"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$RETROFIT"
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'

//play
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$PLAY_SERVICE"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$PLAY_SERVICE"

//push
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$FIREBASE_VERSION"

//mutlidex
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
//image
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
//log
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
//scan
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'
//others
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: That error message you posted doesn't seem complete. What output was before the message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using different version of the same libraries.

```
final FIREBASE_VERSION = '10.0.1'
final PLAY_SERVICE = '10.2.6
```

Keep in mind that Firebase has a dependency with google play services libraries.